# Adding range for NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have an array with 32 objects inside. I am currently trying to figure out a way in which I can display only certain objects inside the array on my page. For example I want to display objects within index 10-18 only. I tried slicing the array to add the range and it works but the problem is, I can't have any of the objects repeat on the same page. So if the objects to be displayed are only 10-18, each object should only be displayed once and in random order so here's how the code I tried looks:

```
NSArray *slice;
slice = [arrayList subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(5,7)];
int i = arc4random() % [slice count];
int k = arc4random() % [slice count];
int j = arc4random() % [slice count]
[self.btnRand1 setTitle:[slice objectAtIndex: i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
[self.btnRand2 setTitle:[slice objectAtIndex: j] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:j];
[self.btnRand3 setTitle:[slice objectAtIndex: k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:k];
```

I need the removeObjectAtIndex to remove the objects that have already been used within the array, but given that I'm using slice to select objects within a certain objects only, it does not work and certain objects would be repeated within the range. And as I've read, you can't use it for NSArrays at all.

How can I add a range for this that won't repeat any of the objects within selected range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make slice a mutable array. You get your first random index, then delete that entry from the array. Repeat that as many times as you want, up to the number of items in slice.

Comment: Thank you! Quick question though, am I doing right by declaring 3 different integer value to get random values for each button and remove the used object?

Comment: @user1597438, well, not in the way you have it in your question. You need to get one random number, set your title, then remove the object from the array. Then repeat those 3 steps. The way you have it in your question, if k or j were pointing to the last item in the array, the program would crash, because after removing i, the array wouldn't have that index any more.

Comment: So basically, just use one integer i.e. int i, get the first random index, delete it, then get the second random index using i then delete it, etc?

Comment: @user1597438, yes, you could do it that way, in a loop for instance.